# Can I use context-sensitive functions in SQLAlchemy with parameters?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's a little table for holding IP address ranges in the form of a start address, end address, and number of IPs within the range

```
class IpRange(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_range'
    ip_range_id = Column(Integer, Sequence('ip_range_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    start_ip = Column(String(15))
    end_ip = Column(String(15))
    num_ips = Column(Integer)
```

What I'd love to do is be able to create an object using a variety of styles, and have the class figure out how to populate its own fields.

```
foo = IpRange(ip='192.168.0.1')
foo = IpRange(ip='192.168.0.0/24')
foo = IpRange(ip='192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255')
```

It wouldn't be too hard to write a function that could parse various IP address/range notations:

```
def parseIp(desired_format):
    ... stuff to parse any valid IP address/network format ...
    if desired_format == 'start':
        return start_ip
    if desired_format == 'end':
        return end_ip
    if desired_format == 'num_ips':
        return num_ips
```

And I was hoping I could then use the `default` method for my Columns to get the data that each column needed:

```
class IpRange(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_range'
    ip_range_id = Column(Integer, Sequence('ip_range_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    start_ip = Column(String(15), default=parseIp('start'))
    end_ip = Column(String(15), default=parseIp('end'))
    num_ips = Column(Integer, default=parseIp('num_ips')
```

However, that is not valid SQLAlchemy syntax.  The documentation speaks of [context-sensitive default columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions), but the syntax does not allow parameters to be passed to the function.  So even though I could call the function with `default=parseIp`, I wouldn't be able to tell it what kind of return value I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this within Column specification for SQLAlchemy?

Or as an alternative idea, should I turn parseIp into a helper script that just generates the new IpRange object itself and returns it back to the caller?  Something like:

```
def parseIp(ipstring):
    ... parse data ...
    return IpRange(start_ip=parsed_start_ip, end_ip=parsed_end_ip, num_ips=parsed_num_ips)

>>> ipobj = parseIp('192.168.0.0/24')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the constructor. Example:

```
class IpRange(Base):
    def __init__(self, ip=None, **kwargs):
        if ip is not None:
            self.start_ip, self.end_ip = my_super_awesome_cidr_parser(ip)
        else:
            super(IpRange, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I don't fully understand how that works (the last line is particularly mysterious), but it does indeed work.  Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeAdams Last line calls the superclass's (`Base`) constructor, allowing you to use the default behavior, which is to set attributes by keyword arguments (e.g. `IpRange(start_ip="...", end_ip="...")`). Documentation for `super()` is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: I think I understand.  It makes sense that the right thing to do (if no "ip" is specified) is to create an `IpRange` object the traditional way (`foo = IpRange(start_ip='...')`).  I guess I thought that we needed to use the original `__init__` for `IpRange`, but I believe what you're telling me is that there was never an `__init__` for IpRange, only one for `Base`.   One other question - why do you call `super(IpRange, self)` rather than just `super(IpRange)` ?

Comment: @GeorgeAdams Short answer: it's just how you're supposed to do superclass calls. Long answer: it has to do with multiple inheritance. When you deal with multiple inheritance, the order in which methods are resolved is called method resolution order (mro), which cannot be inferred directly from the class itself. As an example, `class Foo(IpRange, Bar): pass` has the order `Foo`, `IpRange`, `Bar`, `Base`. As you can see, which `__init__` method you call depends on what object you have, not just the class itself.